# Populate a userform Combobox with a list of subdirectory names in a defined directory

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I apologize if this question was answered previously on this board. My searches didn't turn up what I'm looking for. I am a VBA novice and would like to know if there is a way to populate a userform combobox with the names of all subdirectories contained within a predefined directory (I need the list to be updated every time the userform is launched). I've seen some code that does this on other websites but they were for earlier versions of Excel and I could not get them to work. I am using Excel 2007. I appreciate any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Are you just looking for the 1st level sub directories or multilevel? For example `Temp` is the parent folder. And these are the 1st level sub directories `C:\Temp\Fol1`,`C:\Temp\Fol2` and these go deep... `C:\Temp\Fol1\1\2`,`C:\Temp\Fol2\3\4`

Comment: Post the code you tried - what works should not have changed much between earlier versions and XL2007

Comment: @SiddharthRout You can also edit the title, keyword stuffing is cause for edit.

Comment: Please have a look at/comment on/accept my answer. Not giving any reaction at all is rather impolite.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to respond. The code posted below seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks you very muh\ch for all of the help. This saves me so much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Dim name

  For Each name In ListDirectory(Path:="C:\", AttrInclude:=vbDirectory, AttrExclude:=vbSystem Or vbHidden)
    Me.ComboBox1.AddItem name
  Next name
End Sub

Function ListDirectory(Path As String, AttrInclude As VbFileAttribute, Optional AttrExclude As VbFileAttribute = False) As Collection
  Dim Filename As String
  Dim Attribs As VbFileAttribute

  Set ListDirectory = New Collection

  ' first call to Dir() initializes the list
  Filename = Dir(Path, AttrInclude)

  While Filename <> ""
    Attribs = GetAttr(Path & Filename)
    ' to be added, a file must have the right set of attributes
    If Attribs And AttrInclude And Not (Attribs And AttrExclude) Then
      ListDirectory.Add Filename, Path & Filename
    End If
    ' fetch next filename
    Filename = Dir
  Wend
End Function
```

A few notes, since you said you had little experience with VBA.

- Always have `Option Explicit` in effect. No excuses.
- `Dir()` is used in VB to list files.
- Collections are a lot more convenient than arrays in VBA.
- There are named parameters available in function calls (`name:=value)`. You don't have to use them, but they help to make sense of long argument lists. Argument order is irrelevant if you use named parameters. You cannot mix named and unnamed parameters, though.
- You can have optional arguments with default values.
- Note that assigning to the function name (`ListDirectory` in this case) sets the result of a function. You can therefore use the function name directly as a variable inside that function.
- Set `AttrInclude` to `-1` if you want to return all types of files. Conveniently, `-1` is the numerical value of `True`., i.e. `ListDirectory("C:\", True)`.
- Set `AttrExclude` to `0` if you want to exclude no files. Conveniently, `0` is the numerical value of `False`., i.e. `ListDirectory("C:\", True, False)`, which also is the default.
- All logical operators in VB 6.0 are bit-wise, hence you can check whether a file is a directory by using `If Attribs And VbDirectory Then ...`
- You can combine multiple bit values with `Or`, e.g. `vbSystem Or vbHidden`.
- Consequently, you can filter directories with a simple bit-wise logic check.
- Use the Object Browser (hit F2) to inspect available Functions, Types and Constants, for example the constants in the `VbFileAttribute` enum.